# Angular+PrimeNG+Sakai skeleton project: rerouting sakai demo

Tags: angular, routes, sakai

I have cloned the Sakai angular skeleton from here:
`git clone https://github.com/primefaces/sakai-ng.git`

By default, the 'landing' URL points to the Sakai demo.
I want my base URL to point to my application, while keeping Sakai's demo as a reference (at least during the dev phase).
For that, I want to reroute the whole sakai demo to a 'sakai' route, in such a way that:

- "**myUrl/#/sakai**" takes me to the Sakai Dashboard,
- "**MyUrl/#/sakai/uikit/formlayout**" takes me to the specific 'UIKit/Form
  Layout' demo,
- etc for every Sakai demo page...

So in my app-routing.module.ts, I have done:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    // My Application
    //{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },

    // Sakai
    {
        path: 'sakai', component: AppLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
            { path: 'uikit', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/uikit/uikit.module').then(m => m.UikitModule) },
            { path: 'utilities', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/utilities/utilities.module').then(m => m.UtilitiesModule) },
            { path: 'documentation', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/documentation/documentation.module').then(m => m.DocumentationModule) },
            { path: 'blocks', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/primeblocks/primeblocks.module').then(m => m.PrimeBlocksModule) },
            { path: 'pages', loadChildren: () => import('./sakai/components/pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule) },
        ],
    },
    // code continues...
```

But doing so doesn't work properly with the demo's left-side menu as it keeps using the old route for the links:
`MyUrl/#/uikit/formlayout`
instead of :
`MyUrl/#/sakai/uikit/formlayout`

I tried to fiddle inside the Sakai components' own routing modules without success.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the dashboard routerLinks in

```
src/app/layout/app.menu.component.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to comment the provider's section for LocationStrategy and hashLocationStrategy in the app.module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgY5U.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).